# Ingress and AWS Application Load Balancer

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

Is there anyway to inspect the mappings between ingress resources created in EKS and Application Load Balancers created by AWS Load Balancer Controller?

My understanding is that an ALB gets created by AWS LBC for an ingress of class "alb". This ALB should get deleted after the ingress resource is deleted.

But this doesn't happen sometimes. Likely because I messed around with other related resources such as statefulset, service or pod. (or could it be due to repeated deployment without deleting first?)

So is there a way to see the link between an ingress and its corresponding ALB in AWS?

Answer (score 2):

> is there a way to see the link between an ingress and its corresponding ALB in AWS?

You can use this command to print the ALB created for each Ingress in your cluster: `kubectl get ingress --all-namespaces --output jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{@.metadata.name}{"\t"}{@.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].hostname}{"\n"}'`